# aws dynamodb connection pools full warning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to make 500 queries each time on DynamoDB with multithreading and get a bunch of warnings like this

```
WARNING:  Connection pool is full, discarding connection: dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

I noticed that I still get 500 responses even with these warnings, so it's a not fatal error for sure. 
from this [link](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/619) I learned that the default `max_pool_connections` is 10 and I can increase it by doing this

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", config=botocore.client.Config(max_pool_connections=100))
```

after this I don't get warning any more! My question is if I increase the `max_pool_connections`, does this really speed up the query response?(I'll do a performance test later) and does this increase my monthly bill for aws? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your cores/threads/processes. Basically you need a pool size depending on your capacity.

Comment: Default value of max_workers for ThreadPoolExecuter is min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4), so in this case I should set `max_pool_connections` = 32? Per my test when It still get some warning in that case, and no warnings if it's set to 100. If it's set too high, what's the consequence? thanks